# what is the relationship between rated voltage and angular speed frequency in an AC generator?

Tags: power, ac, electromagnetism, generator, electric-machine

in Ac generator, the internal voltage is directly proportional to the mechanical speed by the equation:
E = K * magnetic flux * mechanical speed

but does this hold also for the terminal voltage? I personally believe it is not! but, for example, the solution of the following problem is done by assuming :

V2/V1 = 50 /  60
[image: example problem]
why is it true?

Comment: I am adding this comment for future pilgrims who find this question by web search. Practical generators can change the field strength in the rotor, so they can regulate voltage to some degree even as speed changes. If you use a bldc as a generator, then you would give up that ability, and open circuit voltage would be proportional to speed.

Answer (score 1):

The generated voltage is directly and linearly proportional to frequency, at least for 50 Hz vs 60 Hz. The line-to-neutral terminal voltage is the generated voltage minus the voltage drop across the armature impedance. Ignoring the resistance, the impedance at 60 Hz is 0.9 ohms. That is also proportional to frequency.